# Codeigniter how to Subtract the quantity of damaged item from product in stock quantity

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello please help with this code... I don't know what I am doing wrong....anyways I am new to codeigniter

I am trying to less the quantity of a product instock everytime the product is entered into the damaged-products table

Please check the code i have, it works adding the damaged product but the quantity in the product table remain unchanged.... Help please

```
public function addDamaged($data = array()) {
    if($this->db->insert('damaged', $data)) { 
        $dam_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        foreach ($data as $da) {
            $da['dam_id'] = $dam_id;
            $product = $this->site->getProductByID($id);
            $this->db->update('products',
                array('quantity' => ($product->quantity - $da['dam_qty'])),
                array('id' => $product->id)
            );
            return $dam_id;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note I have that in my Damaged_model and  CI_model is extended.

Comment: you never define `$da['dam_qty']`, so you're effectively doing `$product->quantity - 0`

Comment: Are you planning on providing multiple items to be added to the 'damaged' table? In other words, will `$data` be an array of damaged items?

Comment: I have a drop down list of products to be added, date, damaged_qty, category in $data array....please make me to understand you better,,

Comment: @BabatundeMisbah  I am asking that, if there are two categories that are in stock: "Shirts" and "Pants" and you have 3 damaged shirts and 2 damaged pants. Would you send information about both damaged categories to `addDamaged()` at the same time?

Comment: Absolutely no! I will add them one after the other.

Comment: @MarcB $da['dam_qty']  is suppose to be a section of input array we are sending to damaged table....how do I define it separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function addDamaged($data = array()) {
    if($this->db->insert('damaged', $data)) { 

        $product = $this->site->getProductByID($data['product_id']);
        $this->db->update('products',
            array('quantity' => ($product->quantity - $da['dam_qty'])),
            array('id' => $product->id)
        );
        return $dam_id;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}